# JavaScript not starting function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have search for some sort of way to do this, but i can't make it work.  It may seem simple but i don't know much about javascript so I have found very little information on the problem and I don't know were is the error at so i'll just briefly explain what it's supposed to do. First here is my code:

```
function showI(a){
    $("#show").fadeIn();
    $("#show .load").fadeIn();
    $("#show").load("ajax/showi.php?id="+a,$("#show .load").fadeOut("fast"))
}
$('.List-item').on('click touchstart',function(){
    var id=$(this).attr("id").split("list-").join();
    showI(id);
})
```

So there's like a button with the class list-item which when click should open a new window with the showI function, but it doesn't(I used before the attribute onClick, but it didn't work on mobile so I changed it to .on(click touchstart))

Any help would be appreciate. (Don't know if this is replicated because i can't find a word to describe the problem)

Comment: What are you expecting `$("#show").load("ajax/showi.php?id="+a,$("#show .load").fadeOut("fast"))` to do? (I've taken a guess below, but...)

Comment: it loads content from a php page to display in the bar, but soofar the function has worked propperly for me just the new part, the on.(click touchstart) isn't working for me.

Comment: I know what `.load` does, I was talking about the second argument you're passing it.

Comment: Are the `.List-item` elements loaded by the `load` call, or (more likely) by some other `.load` call? (And do you really have that capital `L` in there??)

Comment: wow just realized that it was a capital letter problem. I now feel kind of stupid T_T, yea everithing is working fine.

Comment: :-) Happens to us all sometimes... The callback thing below still applies. Best,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
$("#show").load("ajax/showi.php?id="+a,$("#show .load").fadeOut("fast"))
```

**calls** `$("#show .load").fadeOut("fast")` and then passes its return value into `load` as a second argument, exactly the way `foo(bar())` **calls** `bar` and then passes its return value into `foo`.

If you're looking for a completion callback, you need to wrap that in a function:

```
$("#show").load("ajax/showi.php?id="+a, function() {
    $("#show .load").fadeOut("fast");
});
```